# Can't connect my mongoDB database from my local machine

Tags: mongodb

**UPDATED:**

I just start to deal with a new VPS and i am trying to connect its port 27017 (mongodb database) from localhost (using robomongo).

It's working on my localhost machine and with another remote server, but i can't connect mongodb on this VPS, what could cause this issue ?
I start it this way:

```
mongod --setParameter enableLocalhostAuthBypass=0 --config /etc/mongodb.conf --fork
```

with the `auth = true` uncommented in the /etc/mongodb.conf file (but it looks like the issue is not that i can't auth but mongodb is not responding at all).
When i start `mongo admin -u root -p root` by being connected with SSH, it works great (i can connect my database) and i can see that mongodb is well listenning on the port 27017.

But when i try to access it from my local machine, it can't establish the connection, and if i try to connect it with my browser, i am supposed to get a mongodb error message: `You are trying to access MongoDB on the native driver port. For http diagnostic access, add 1000 to the port number` but i don't, i just have a failure page with Chrome (and the port 28017 is not responding either).

How to solve this ? My VPS is brand new and i could need to install more packages but i really don't see what could be need for this, it also looks like a firewall issue, like something prevent mongodb and response before the request could reach it, i have juste installed apache2 and nginx and they are not running so i really don't see...

Comment: How does nginx was suppose to answer on port 27017? Did you configure it to listen to that port?

Comment: It has nothing to do with DNS.

Comment: Yes i realize that it's probably nothing to do with the DNS but i don't know where to look for...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, I have found the issue!

There is a line `bind_ip 127.0.0.1` in the `/etc/mongod.conf` file.
It provides access only to the specified IP address to mongodb.

You should create an array of IPs and edit the config file as:

```
bind_ip [127.0.0.1, x.x.x.x, ...]
```

Where `x.x.x.x` is your IP.

Comment: `It provides access only to the specified IP address to mongodb.` Thanks for your tip. Changed from localhost to 127.0.0.1 in mongoDB URI connection string and application connected with mongod

Answer (score 1):

i resolved this issue with file(/etc/mongod.conf)
commenting out as follows:

#bindIp: 127.0.0.1  # Listen to local interface only, comment to listen on all interfaces.

Comment: Just to point out something important about this answer : commenting the `bind_ip` config will allow anyone to try to authenticate to your database. If you do this, **be careful to protect it with a password** (which Mongo doesn't have by default).